# One Boxplot for multiple dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, boxplot

I am trying to make a boxplot that shows multiple dataframe.

right now I have a script that gives me three subplots of sns boxplots, but is there a way that I can be all three data plots in a single boxplots, all columns side by side? The picture is that I want as an output

This is the current code that gives me three subplots. [image]

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(3,1)

sns.boxplot(x ='type', y ='value', data =df1.sort_values('value'), ax =axes[0]).set_title('A')
sns.boxplot(x ='type', y ='value', data =df2.sort_values('value'), ax =axes[1]).set_title('B')
sns.boxplot(x ='type', y ='value', data =df3.sort_values('value'), ax =axes[2]).set_title('C')
plt.xticks(rotation='horizontal')
sns.set(rc = {'figure.figsize':(20,30)})
sns.set(font_scale=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Add a name column to the current dataframe, and then join the dataframe vertically. Then `sns.catplot` it and specify the type as boxplot. For more details, here is an example at the bottom of the [official reference page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#seaborn.boxplot).

Comment: sorry for late response! it worked promptly. thank you so much!